# SKLearn - Cannot import LinearModel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import `LinearModel` from SKLearn:

```
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin, LinearModel
```

I can see with my own eyes, that the class is in `base.py` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L417), but the import doesn't work. Why? How can I fix this?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'LinearModel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of sklearn v24 the previous solution `from sklearn.linear_model.base import LinearModel` doesn't work anymore.

New workaround is to import whatever class you need/want to inherit directly. For me, that was `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do? As far as I can see it, LinearModel is only a base class.

Is this maybe what you are looking for?
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares

Edit:

Oh and by the way, if you really need the base class, I believe it is located in sklearn.linear_model.base. Import it using:

```
from sklearn.linear_model.base import LinearModel
```

Comment: I'm trying to make my own version of the OLS, that's why I need it.

Comment: So yes, I'd need to import the base class.

Comment: Hey I just added the location of the base class. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5c4b1bb23192a137ac22ced229c50d6b69859ac6/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L225

Comment: I have to use `from sklearn.linear_model._base import LinearModel` for `scikit_learn==0.24.1`